# Integer Partition Algo - Converting from Java to Python

Tags: python, int

I've come across a question when I was looking at a bunch of algorithms for fun. The algorithm that I solved (in Java) asks me to list all the partitions of an integer. So the partitions of 4 should receive the following printed output:

4 , 3+1,  2+2,  2+1+1, 1+1+1+1

This is my code in Java:

```
 public static void partition(int n) {
        partition(n, n, "");
    }
    public static void partition(int n, int max, String prefix) {
        if (n == 0) {
            StdOut.println(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) {
            partition(n-i, i, prefix + " " + i);
        }
    }
```

However, when I tried to convert my Java code to Python, I get the "recursion depth exceed" error. Here it is:

```
def partition_rec(N):
    def part(N,maximum = N, prefix = ""):
        if(N==0):
            print(prefix)
            return
        for i in range(N-1):
           part(N-i,i,prefix + " " + str(i))
    return part(N)
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have changed your for loop. In Java it is running in reverse direction. In python equivalent you are running it form `0 to N - 2`.

Change your for loop to: -

```
for i in range(min(maximum, N), 0, -1):
```

to be exact. Since, loop is form `n` to `1`.

`-1` is the step value, and it runs the range in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

When I change your code to match the Java version, it works for me:

```
def partition_rec(N):
    def part(N,maximum = N, prefix = ""):
        if(N==0):
            print(prefix)
            return
        for i in range(min(maximum, N), 0, -1): # changed this line
           part(N-i,i,prefix + " " + str(i))
    return part(N)

partition_rec(4)
```